# Error while importing CSV to sql using powershell

Tags: powershell, import-csv

The below variable alone is not working during the import. I am new into entire coding area and I think this is some basics which I don't understand.

```
$csvPath =$(Get-Date).AddMonths(-1) Get-Item \\SMC01702.WWG00M.ROOTDOM.NET\PROG_D$\1200000024\FSSL-ACCOUNTING\TCCS\*.csv* | where { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $csvPath} | Foreach {“File Name: ” + $_.Name}
```

When I try with the direct path as below it does work, however when $csvpath is applied it fails. can someone please help.

Other variables are:

```
#Variables
$csvDelimiter = ";"
$serverName = "sm024591.wwg00m.rootdom.net"
$databaseName = "FSSL-Accounting"
$tableName = "TCCS"
$tableSchema = "import"

#Truncate the Table that has older data
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $serverName -Database $databaseName -Query "TRUNCATE TABLE $tableschema.$tableName"


#Import the CSV and Delimit the data for ';' / Validate the input
$data = Import-Csv -Path '\\SMC01702.WWG00M.ROOTDOM.NET\PROG_D$\1200000024\FSSL-ACCOUNTING\TCCS\TCCS_122022.csv' -Delimiter $csvDelimiter
```

$data | select -first 10

```
#Write the data to SQL Server
Write-SqlTableData -DatabaseName $databaseName -TableName TCCS -SchemaName import -ServerInstance $serverName -InputData $data
```

But when I try with the variable

```
#Variables
$csvDelimiter = ";"
$serverName = "sm024591.wwg00m.rootdom.net"
$databaseName = "FSSL-Accounting"
$tableName = "TCCS"
$tableSchema = "import"

#Truncate the Table that has older data
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $serverName -Database $databaseName -Query "TRUNCATE TABLE     $tableschema.$tableName"


#Import the CSV and Delimit the data for ';' / Validate the input
$data = Import-Csv -Path $csvPat**h -Delimiter $csvDelimiter
$data | select -first 10

#Write the data to SQL Server
Write-SqlTableData -DatabaseName $databaseName -TableName TCCS -SchemaName import -ServerInstance   $serverName -InputData $data
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and copy-paste the error message you got. Don't add a screenshot.

Comment: You are using a wildcard in the filename.  So use childitem to get filename. 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?force_isolation=true